# Pydantic mangling input

Tags: python, typing, pydantic

In the following example, I can't understand why pydantic is mangling the type input.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Union, List


class Foo(BaseModel):
    bar: Union[str, dict, List[dict]]

f = Foo(bar=[{'foo': 'bar', 'stuff': 'things'}])
assert f.bar == {'foo': 'stuff'}
```

Why is the type changing from a list to a dict and further mangling the keys into a key value pair? Don't know if this is pydantic specific or just typing issues.

And as a followup, what can I do to fix this so that the types aren't mangled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer came from [asking in the repo](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/3800#issuecomment-1033418264).

Basically this was fixed in the most recent version of pydantic if you include a [smart union](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/model_config/#smart-union) config value.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Union, List


class Foo(BaseModel, smart_union=True):
    bar: Union[str, dict, List[dict]]

f = Foo(bar=[{'foo': 'bar', 'stuff': 'things'}])
assert f.bar == [{'foo': 'bar', 'stuff': 'things'}]
```